# How to merge dataframes on timestamped index of differing time intervals

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have multiple dataframes containing data timestamped with month, week, day, hour and minute respectively. How can I merge so as to keep all the data at each row? That is to say, how do I merge so that the month&week&day&hour values are carried down the rows that contain the minute values for each month?

Comment: Can you add your dataframes?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the exact question. However, if you mean you have multiple columns to merge as a single date column, maybe this may help. Otherwise, could you please add your dataframes?

```
import pandas as pd


df = {'year': [1923, 1919], 'month': [4, 5], 'day': [23,19], 'minute': [22,22], 
     'second': [22,22], 'ms':[22,22]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=df)

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df[['year','month','day', 'minute', 'second', 'ms']])
```